# When we call thread.start() which thread is invoked first

Tags: java, multithreading

Here my code is:

```
    public class Child extends Thread {

        public void run(){
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
                {   
                    System.out.println("child thread");
                }
            }
        }
    }

class ThreadTest{
    public static void main(String []a) {
        Child child=new Child();
        **child.start();**      
        synchronized (child) 
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {   
                System.out.println("parent thread");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It first prints "parent thread" after that it prints "child thread" but my doubt is, when we invoke start() method  there is a chance to invoke child thread before main thread. But it always prints "parent thread" after that "child thread". can any one explain?

Comment: this happens because `synchronized(child)` is entered before `synchronized(this)` in `Child#run()`, occasionally. There is no guarantee.

Comment: In this case it's up to the scheduler to decide whether to immediately schedule the newly created thread or not. There are no guarantees for any outcome over the other, not even that it'll be a mixture of the two. If you want to enforce an order, you need something like a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Your edit review is very disappointing.

Comment: @Tom my fault, it's by mistake

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Well lucky for you it wasn't a trial ;P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere inside the `child.start()` call (i.e., before start() returns) the new thread is created, and it becomes eligible to run.  From that point on, it's a race to see which thread will reach it's respective `synchronized(...)` block first.  There's no way to know which one will win, and there's no reason to think that it will be the same winner every time.

---

P.S.:  Synchronizing on a `Thread` object is not a good idea.  The `Thread` class also synchronizes on `Thread` instances for its own purposes, and there is a risk that your use of the Thread object as a lock could interfere with the Thread class's use of it.

A good habit is to synchronize on a private object.

```
class MyClass {
    private final Object myLock = new Object();

    SomeType someMethod(...) {
        synchronized(myLock) {
            ....
         }
    }
}
```